# Unable to write dataframe in R as Update-Statement to Postgis/PostgresSQL

Tags: r, postgresql, rpostgresql

I have the following dataframe:

```
library(rpostgis)
library(RPostgreSQL)
library(glue)
df<-data.frame(elevation=c(450,900),
               id=c(1,2))
```

Now I try to upload this to a table in my PostgreSQL/Postgis database. My connection (dbConnect) is working for "SELECT"-Statements properly. However, I tried two ways of updating a database table with this dataframe and both failed.

First:

```
 pgInsert(postgis,name="fields",data.obj=df,overwrite = FALSE, partial.match = TRUE,
         row.names = FALSE,upsert.using = TRUE,df.geom=NULL)

2 out of 2 columns of the data frame match database table columns and will be formatted for database insert.
Error: x must be character or SQL
```

I do not know what the error is trying to tell me as both the values in the dataframe and table are set to integer.

Second:

```
sql<-glue_sql("UPDATE fields SET elevation ={df$elevation} WHERE 
+               id = {df$id};", .con = postgis)
> sql
<SQL> UPDATE fields SET elevation =450 WHERE 
id = 1;
<SQL> UPDATE fields SET elevation =900 WHERE 
id = 2;
dbSendStatement(postgis,sql)
<PostgreSQLResult>
```

In both cases no data is transferred to the database and I do not see any Error logs within the database.

Any hint on how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

It is a mistake from my site, I got `glue_sql` wrong. To correctly update the database with every query created by `glue_sql` you have to loop through the created object like the following example:

```
for(i in 1:max(NROW(sql))){
   dbSendStatement(postgis,sql[i])
}
```